# PHP - Placing an IF statement into a variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I want to place an if statement into a variable in order to reduce the lines of code... for example I want to do this:

```
$empty = if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']))
if($empty){ // echo message; 
}
elseif(!$empty){ ///echo message; 
}
```

Can something like the above be produced? Or am I making things too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$message = ( empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']) ) ? 'empty': 'not empty';
echo $message;
```

Comment: No, the ternary operator is basically a shorthand for if/else - think of it like (if) ? true : false;

Answer (score 7):

Just omit the if:

```
$empty = empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$empty = (empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password'])) ? 0 : 1;

if($empty){ // Not empty message here...; 

}
else{ ///Empty message here....; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of ternary operator:

```
echo empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']) ? 'empty message' : 'Not empty message';
```

Rather than getting value of `$empty` and printing it, you can directly use `echo` and ternary operator.